# Normal distribution with integer numbers

Tags: normal-distribution, statistics, poisson, statistical-test

I'm running into some quite interesting problems over here. It is about creating a normal distribution with integer numbers in the range of 1 to 5 (1,2,3,4,5). Technically, it is a Poisson distribution with the shape of a normal distribution.

My question: When I create a distribution as mentioned above, tests for normality fail (p < 0.01)(Shapiro Wilk Test, Kolomogorov Smirnov Test), as I created a pool of normally distributed numbers which I rounded:

xRND<-round(rnorm(179,mean=2.9,sd=1))
table(xRND)
xRND
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
2 14 41 67 45 9 1

Is there any test that helps me to check for a normal distribution shape?

Best regards,
St.

Comment: Here you will find a picture for the graph: http://images.gutefrage.net/media/fragen/bilder/statistik-test-auf-normalitaet/0_big.jpg

Comment: Something like this here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32405/how-is-poisson-distribution-different-to-normal-distribution

Answer (score 0):

From my prospective the Shapiro Wilk Test is the test with the best goodness. Working with rounded values will have an impact to the result. There is a method called Sheppard-correction to calculate a adapted `W`-value (test statistic) considering rounding of the tested values:

[image]

with ω as the rounding difference.
([here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro-Wilk-Test) the link to the German source)